# Where is (or was) Project HARP's Yuma Arizona space gun?

Tags: 1960s

I found myself reading about [Project HARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_HARP), the High Altitude Research Project, which was a project funded to explore the possibility of creating high speed guns that could essentially replace certain types of rockets. In 1966, the third and final gun was constructed in Yuma, Arizona.

I am an hour away from Yuma Arizona for the next few days. Is the gun still there? Where was it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Yuma Proving Ground](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuma_Proving_Ground) is not accessible by civilians unless you have contacts in the Army. The test site is located in the KOFA Range. The 16" gun is at (old) gun position 10. I have posted a satellite image below with the coordinates:

[image: 16" HARP gun at Yuma Proving Grounds]

As you can see, the gun is still in place. The tubes to the north of the gun are alternative barrels.

There is a HARP gun on Barbados that you can visit.